# Matching a set of items containing arrays in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have the following data

```
[
  { name: 'A', values: [1, 2, 3 ,4] },
  { name: 'B', values: [5, 6, 7, 8] }
]
```

and I have a `mongodb` that has the following items in a collection:

```
#1 { name: 'A', values: [1, 2, 3 ,4], path: '...' },
#2 { name: 'B', values: [8, 9, 5, 7], path: '...' },
#3 { name: 'B', values: [5, 6, 7, 8], path: '...' },
#4 { name: 'C', values: [9, 10, 11, 12], path: '...' }
```

Now I want to query the `path`s that match my 2 items `A` and `B` from the `data` (Items `#1` and `#3`). Is that possible *`edit: with a single query`*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the `data` and use query inside the `map` function by making it asynchronous

```
const data = [
  { name: 'A', values: [1, 2, 3 ,4] },
  { name: 'B', values: [5, 6, 7, 8] }
]

const result = []
await Promise.all(data.map(async(d) => {
  result.push(await db.collection.findOne(d))
}))
```

Or even with the single query

```
await db.collection.find(
  {
    name: { $in: data.map(({ name }) => name) },
    values: { $in: data.map(({ values }) => values) }
  }
)
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I meant with a single query… I updated my question

Comment: Updated my answer